# Why does Tigris call Coriolanus Snow a "good person"?

Tags: suzanne-collins, the-ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes

Upon learning about Coriolanus Snow being forced to join the Peacekeepers due to his cheating in the Hunger Games, Tigris said the following:

> "You were set up to fail," said Tigris. "The Hunger Games are an unnatural, vicious punishment. How could **a good person like you** be expected to go along with them?"
> "You musn't say that to anyone but me. It isn't safe," Coriolanus warned her.

Snow at a minimum doesn't disagree with this assessment, and there are multiple hints in the books that he's horrified by the entire process (such as his insistence on feeding the Tributes due to his disgust at the Gamemakers not feeding them in days). Nevertheless, his selfishness and manipulativeness always seems to be competing with his morality throughout the book, and the *Hunger Games* books obviously imply that his selfishness wins out in the end as he eventually becomes the [ruthless, albeit likely not sadistic,](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166134/is-president-snow-sadistic-or-simply-ruthless) President of Panem. Tigris is also later shown to have joined the resistance movement, having evidently fallen out with Snow at some point.

Why does Tigris say this? Is she mistaken about Snow's character, or did he become a bad person later?