# Was Snow still following his morality in the Hunger Games series?

Tags: character-analysis, suzanne-collins, the-hunger-games, the-ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes

Related: [Why does Tigris call Coriolanus Snow a "good person"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14823/why-does-tigris-call-coriolanus-snow-a-good-person)

*The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes* contains the following:

> Coriolanus felt disconnected from their "romantic notions" [about the war], as he didn't share a romanticized view of the war. Courage in battle was often necessary because of someone's poor planning. He had no idea if he would take a bullet for Festus and had no interest in finding out. As to the noble ideas of the Capital, did he really believe that? **What he desired had little to do with nobility and everything to do with being in control. Not that he didn't have a strong moral code; certainly he did. But almost everything in war between its declaration and the victory parades, seemed a waste of resources.**

Indeed, throughout the book, his selfishness and desire for control frequently seems at odds with his sense of morality (such as his horror at the treatment of the Hunger Games contestants).

He later tells Katniss Everdeen that, whatever his other flaws, he was not wasteful. He clearly continued with his desire to be in control as President, as well as his desire not to waste resources, but what about his "strong moral code?" Did he continue in that, or did he gradually abandon that in his desire for control?